# Python script that finds post by a specific user on an xenoforo forum

Tags: python

I want to make a python scirpt that can prints out all posts in a thread by a specific user. I know what librarys should be used but am unable to find the post's using html. How would I go about doing this ?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/the-wizard-of-woah-and-the-      impossible-methods-of-necromancy.337233/"
data_1 = requests.get(url)
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(data_1.content)
users = soup_data.find_all("li" , {"data-author": ""})
```

Comment: According to the documentation that should work. Assuming that you are searching something like: posts = soup_data.find_all("li", {"data-author": "FriedCFour"})

Comment: How do i remove all the html formating ?

Comment: what do you want? I mean remove the formatting and keep what?

Comment: for post in posts: content = post.find('div', {'class':'messageContent'}).text.strip().encode("utf-8") as said in the answer by slayer

Comment: keeps giving me the error 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Because your calling `find` on the variable you set to `findAll`. `findAll` returns a collections of objects and is not an object that alows those methods itself. Hence, the loop which loops through the elements you can then call `find` on those elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to find the messages by the author wrong, specifying `data-author` like this is looking for a message in the `ol` messageList tag such that the `data-author` section in the `li` tag is a blank string, but every message (li) has a data-author attribute. Hence, no results

```
import requests, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/the-wizard-of-woah-and-the-impossible-methods-of-necromancy.337233/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.content, "html.parser")

#To find all posts from a specific user everything below this is for all posts
specific_messages = soup.findAll('li', {'data-author': 'author_name'})


#To find every post from every user
posts = {}

message_container = soup.find('ol', {'id':'messageList'}) 
messages = message_container.findAll('li', recursive=0)
for message in messages:
    author = message['data-author']
    #or don't encode to utf-8 simply for printing in shell
    content = message.find('div', {'class':'messageContent'}).text.strip().encode("utf-8")
    if author in posts:
        posts[author].append(content)
    else:
        posts[author] = [content]
pprint.pprint(posts)
```

Comment: where do i Insert the authors name ?